# Rails deleting development.log lines (not file itself)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it safe to delete the lines in the development.log in your rails application?

I've been developing for awhile and that file now has over 50 millions lines...It's in the gitignore file so it's not causing problems when using git but I access it a lot and have to wait for it to load then scroll to the bottom...

I would imagine it's fine to delete the lines (not the file itself) but I just thought i'd ask the experts first.

Thanks guys/gals

Comment: Instead of opening the log itself, you could use the command `tail development.log` in your CLI and eventually give the arg `-n 35` to see the 35 last lines. Also works with the command `head some_log.log -n 10` to see the first 10 rows of the `some_log.log` file without loading it entirely.

Comment: Oh yea - that is what I do now :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

you can delete the file itself if you are not going to need the history. Restart server and it will be automatically created back again.

If you don't want to delete the file, emptying it is perfectly fine.

```
echo "" > log/development.log
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I thought it'd be fine but just wanted to ask first.

Answer (score 13):

You can do it automatically on server startup by creating a file `clear_development_log.rb` in `config/initializers`:

```
if Rails.env.development?
  `rake log:clear`
end
```

Or check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/pahanix/885671) to only trigger that if the log is large.

Comment: Pretty handy gist. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Thanks!! You are awesome :)